# Dtcping test passes but still have a Communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactions, transactionscope, msdtc

DTCPing tool says everything should be fine. The actual exception is:

> ```
> System.Transactions.TransactionManagerCommunicationException:
> ```
>
> Communication with the underlying transaction manager has failed. --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The MSDTC transaction
>   manager was unable to push the transaction to the destination
>   transaction manager due to communication problems. Possible causes
>   are: a firewall is present and it doesn't have an exception for the
>   MSDTC process, the two machines cannot find each other by their
>   NetBIOS names, or the support for network transactions is not enabled
>   for one of the two transaction managers. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8004D02A)

The service runs on a VM. Other servers are able to run distributed transactions, so DB box is configured properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good article on this subject here: [Troubleshooting Problems with MSDTC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561924.aspx). It was originally written for BizTalk Server but applies on other server as well.

Since you're running off a VPC, it's possible the DTC shares some identifiers with another machine on the same network. Please check the "Ensure that MSDTC is assigned a unique CID value" chapter in this article (see also http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnlee/archive/2008/09/09/msdtc-on-virtual-machines.aspx), although I believe DTCPing should tell you about it... You can also try `msdtc -uninstall` and `msdtc -install` to fix this.

You should also check if your server are not using some VPN or encryption technology. I kinda remember this can cause issues.

Answer (score 2):

Someone has already mentioned unique IDs, make sure you do that before you do anything else, I've seen people blow up a LOT of time going down other routes only to find out that was all the problem was.

That said, I have found a tool called DTCTester to be more useful than DTCPing.  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/293799

It's a little bit harder to use than DTCPing, but it also tests much closer to what you are normally looking to do which gives you a cleaner test result.

*** Make sure that all possible firewall/filtering software is disabled and/or non-existant ***

I can't stress that enough, I once spent almost 90 minutes trying to convince a cusotmer that his VPN sofware was acting as a personal firewall and blocking incoming sockets.   Once he disabled it, the problems went away.  (the software incidently was Cisco VPN Client, the setting was "Stateful Firewall (Always On)" - yep, it's ALWAYS on :) )

Remember that DTC is two-way traffic, so this has to be true on both sides, and you also need to ensure both machines have 'Enable Network DTC Access" allowed.   I have also found that making sure the DTC settings on both boxes are synchronized generally ensures solid interaction as well.